# placementrules in yunikorn don't work as expected when trying to launch a spark job using the spark-operator

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, spark-operator, google-spark-operator

I've successfully deployed yunikorn on a k8s cluster and can deploy spark application successfully using spark-operator. My problem is that when I want to specify the queue in the sparkapplication, it does not work as expected.

My yunikorn-configs looks like this:

```
    partitions:
      - name: default
        placementrules:
          - name: provided
            create: true
        nodesortpolicy:
          type: binpacking
        queues:
          - name: root
            submitacl: "*"
```

and the annotation in the sparkapplication yaml looks like this:

```
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: "my-spark-app"
  namespace: spark-op
spec:
  sparkVersion: 3.3.1
  driver:
    annotations:
      yunikorn.apache.org/queue: test
.
.
.
  executor:
    annotations:
      yunikorn.apache.org/queue: test
```

The expected behavior is that yunikorn will launch the application in the `root.test` queue, but instead, it launches it in the `root.default` queue.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have the same issue.
Also tried "spark.kubernetes.driver.label.queue" configs, but actually, this not working.
Also tried "root.<QUEUE>" value, but still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the queue using the spark conf?

```
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.label.queue=<QUEUE_NAME>
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.label.queue=<QUEUE_NAME>
```

Ref: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#get-started